# Include child relation

Tags: c#, entity-relationship, ravendb

I got the following document:

```
TodoList
    Id
    TodoItems
        Title
        UserId
```

How can I `Include<UserDocument>()` for each todo item using `Load<>` or `Query<>`?

Edit: I want to fetch a todolist and all related users in the same get without using projection

Comment: How do we get from UserId to UserDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.Include("ToDoItems.UserId").Load<ToDoList>("todolists/1");
```

Comment: What if I want to load a subset of UserDocument?

Comment: You can't do that using an include, you'll have to use a Live Projection